# Game performs poorly when sideloaded

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio

My game runs smooth when I deploy it to my windows phone directly from Visual Studio 2012 in debugging mode.

But when I sideload/deploy the same .xap file with the *Application Deployment Tool*, the game runs much worse.

Why is that happening?

Comment: I don't understand why someone would downvote on this

Comment: Possibly because it isn't much of a problem description other than "it's slow." What have you tried? What does your profiling tell you? If you haven't done any profiling or instrumentation, do so and report back the data if you still don't understand how it correlates to your performance problem. As it stands, this question is very unclear and it will be very hard to provide answers that are not just shots in the dark.